# Как заменить букву каждой строки на заглавную?

Tags: c#

Есть текст.

```
ПриВет землянин.хорошая погода
```

Как из него получить

```
Привет землянин.Хорошая погода
```

То есть сперва всю строку сделать `ToLower`, а потом каждую первую букву сделать с `ToUpper`

Comment: Стандартного метода нет, нужно писать свой метод расширения. Или у вас вопрос о том, как написать такой метод?

Comment: Есть ответ на англоязычном SO ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36089913/6468198)).

Comment: Строки или предложения?